# How to update view when I changed event's attributes?

Tags: fullcalendar

I got an original event object through `eventClick` in a calendar, now I changed some of its attributes like `start` and `end`, and I want to use `updateEvent` to update my view.

What `event` should I pass to `.fullCalendar('updateEvent', event)`?

Comment: Please provide few part of your calendar code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the [FullCalendar Docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/updateEvent/) for updateEvent, you can update the event object in the eventClick callback and send that event back to updateEvent. The calendar will render the changes.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventClick: function(event, element) {

        event.title = "CLICKED!";

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);

    }
});
```

Comment: I'v see the process of drag, when drag stops, `fullCalendar` have changed the `event`'s status, so the `event` passed to the following `updateEvent` is in the final state, `event_start` = `event.start` , `event._end` = `event.end`. Now I change `event.start` and `event.end` , if I set `_start` and `_end` equal to them respectively, `updateEvent` does not work. What should be the value of `_start` and `_end`? stay same with with the original `event`?

Comment: At this point youll probably have to update your post with the code of what you are trying. What i added above is the proper way to update and rerender an event.

Comment: Now the server have been fixed and I retry just change the `start` and `end`, and now it works well...Thanks a lot! 我之前居然没想到，真是醉了

Comment: Good to hear. Happy to help. Please mark as accepted answer if this was the solution. Happy coding